# What is the biblical basis for the Eastern Orthodox concept of Aerial toll houses?

Tags: biblical-basis, eastern-orthodox, hell, confession, demons

I heard about the Eastern Orthodox ['Toll Booth' concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_toll_house) a few days ago. It goes something like this:

After death you go through 20 toll booths manned by demons who ask specific questions about your sins.  If you have committed any unrepented sins you will be doomed to hell.

What biblical basis do Eastern Orthodox theologians give for this concept?

Comment: Where did you hear about this doctrine? I've certainly never heard of it.

Comment: Looks like you're asking about the Eastern Orthodox concept of [Aerial toll house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_toll_house). I'd never heard of it before, but it's definitely a thing! However, this question isn't really quite clear enough. I think you should either focus on the Biblical basis for this belief, or an explanation of it (whether not confessing one sin to these demons definitively sends you to sin.) The question needs to be focused on this specific doctrine and not just whether a lack of confession generally makes you hell-bound.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more focused. I'd recommend asking follow up questions if you want to know more than just the biblical basis.

Comment: @curiousdannii - many thanks for your edit and for the link to the Aeriel Toll House article. Yes, focusing on the biblical basis for this teaching is good.  I hope we will now get some response.

Comment: @curiousdannii – I have just edited my question to replace ‘doctrine’ with ‘concept’ since the link you provided shows the Aerial Toll Houses was never formally promulgated by any Eastern Orthodox ecumenical council.

Comment: DV because question is essentially "What is the [Protestant standard of proof] for a [non-Protestant practice/belief]?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of the soul being escorted to God by angels and having to pass through an aerial realm which is inhabited by wicked spirits seems to be based on Ephesians 6:12:

> For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the powers of this dark world, and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms (NIV)
>
> For we wrestle, not against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this world, against spiritual wickedness in high places. (KJV)

It is worth noting that the concept of souls having to "pay" for their sins by giving an account of compensatory good deeds, else be dragged off into Hades, has never been formally promulgated by any Eastern Orthodox ecumenical council.  Indeed, some Orthodox theologians and bishops have condemned it as heretical and gnostic in origin.

> In 2017, Saint Anthony's Monastery in Florence, Arizona, published a 1,112-page book called The Departure of the Soul According to the Teaching of the Orthodox Church... However, two dedicated chapters in the book The Departure of the Soul According to the Teaching of the Orthodox Church allegedly reveal for the first time over 100 falsifications, misrepresentations, and errors in Puhalo's and Azkoul's writings...  Both writers' works are asserted to contain an inordinate number of gross misrepresentations and errors, all attempting to support their allegedly incorrect opinions about the Orthodox teaching on the toll-houses.   Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_toll_house#Controversy

While looking into this subject, I found a useful article that provides further resources: https://www.orthodoxroad.com/heaven-hell-and-toll-house-resource-page/

Ephesians 6:2 does not, in my opinion, provide a biblical basis for this concept.  However, it was the only tenuous link I could find.  My thanks to curiousdannii for providing the link to that Wiki article.